# Inserting values into BLOB type in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have several columns of BLOB type in my Database.
Not all these columns are needed to be filled since it will contain fingerprint templates. There are cases that users are amputated thus, not all columns are used.

In that situation, what value should I insert in my database? This is my code:

```
public void insertLeftHandBio(Bio bio, String id) {
        try {

            String query = "INSERT INTO fingerprint_left_tbl VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            ps = super.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

            ps.setInt(1, 0);
            ps.setString(2, id);

            //LEFT HAND
            //Left Thumb
            File file = new File("Left Hand Thumb.jpg");
            InputStream stream = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(file);
            ps.setBytes(3, bio.getLeftHandThumbTemplate().serialize());
            ps.setBinaryStream(4, stream);

            //Left Index
            file = new File("Left Hand Index.jpg");
            stream = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(file);
            ps.setBytes(5, bio.getLeftHandIndexTemplate().serialize());
            ps.setBinaryStream(6, stream);

            //Left Middle
            file = new File("Left Hand Middle.jpg");
            stream = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(file);
            ps.setBytes(7, bio.getLeftHandMiddleTemplate().serialize());
            ps.setBinaryStream(8, stream);

            //Left Ring
            file = new File("Left Hand Ring.jpg");
            stream = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(file);
            ps.setBytes(9, bio.getLeftHandRingTemplate().serialize());
            ps.setBinaryStream(10, stream);

            //Left Little
            file = new File("Left Hand Little.jpg");
            stream = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(file);
            ps.setBytes(11, bio.getLeftHandLittleTemplate().serialize());
            ps.setBinaryStream(12, stream);

            int i = ps.executeUpdate();

            if (i < 0) {
                System.out.println("Bio Inserted");
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            ex1.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.cleanUpResources();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What issue you are getting ? any error/exception?

Comment: I had NullPointer but I was expecting it. I got this when template is not registered in a particular finger.. So my problem is, when a particular finger's template is null, what should I insert?

Comment: Need your help guys.

Comment: Please add stacktrace as well in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to insert NULL in the database, so a simple check is enough before calling methods that throw exceptions in the Java program. For example for left hand thumb:

```
if (bio.getLefHandThumbTemplate() != null) {
  File file = new File("Left Hand Thumb.jpg");
  InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
  ps.setBytes(3, bio.getLeftHandThumbTemplate().serialize());
  ps.setBinaryStream(4, stream);
} else {
  ps.setNull(3, Types.BLOB);
  ps.setNull(4, Types.BLOB);
}
```

To avoid duplicate code (5 times for two hands) I suggest you put this inside your `Fingerprint` class (or whatever is called).

Comment: Thanks :3, So I have to set my column to NULLABLE ?